# Regular Expression to capture Double or Single Digit within text

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a reg-ex that will capture a number that can be 1 or 2 digits and would occur in the middle of text, for example..."jdjkj23kljl" or "kjflk2jklj".
Everything I've tried so far only captures either the 2 digit scenario or 1 digit, but not both.

Thanks!

Comment: For improving the answer, please state your flavor, whether you need numbers at the start/end of lines/strings be detected, whether at the start/end of "words" i.e. between whitespaces. Maybe make a complete [mcve]".

Answer (score 1):

If supported by your regex flavor, try `(\d{1,2})`.
Otherwise, more widely supported, try `([0-9][0-9]|[0-9])`.

Explanation:

- `\d` means "any digit" and is more powerful than `[0-9]` (see comment by axiac)
- `{1,2}` means "one or two times
- `[0-9]` means, well, zero to nine
- `[0-9][0-9]` is the crawl-on-hands-and-knees version of "two digits",
  for very limited flavors
- there is a trick with the `...|...`: it needs the longer version first to work for both

Comment: It is worth mentioning that when Unicode is enabled, `\d` and `[0-9]` are not equivalent. `\d` contains `[0-9]` but it also contains the digits used by non-Latin alphabets.

Comment: @axiac Useful info, yes. But it seems clear that OP thinks of 0-9 and does not bother about e.g. wahid, ithnan...; itch, nee, ...

Comment: This will also match numbers with 3 digits and more. Like if you have: "abcd123abcd", it will match 12 and 3

Comment: @Benoit True. Will improve. Assuming I get help by OP.

Answer (score 1):

`(<?=[^0-9])([0-9]{1,2})(?=[^0-9])`

Match every number with 1 or 2 digits that is not between an other number.

**Test**

```
echo -ne "aaa1bb22cc333ddd4444zzz" | egrep -oP "(<?=[^0-9])([0-9]{1,2})(?=[^0-9])"
```

**Output**

> 1
>
> 22

**Edit**

As Yunnosch said, the first solution doesn't take into account number at the begining and at the end of the text. Here another solution for that:

```
echo -ne "0aaa1bb22cc333ddd4444zzz9" | egrep -oP "(<?=[^0-9]|^)([0-9]{1,2})(?=[^0-9]|$)"
```

> 0
>
> 1
>
> 22
>
> 9

Comment: Which egrep version are you using? I cannot reproduce your solution.

Comment: This is not supposed to match at start/end of line/string, is it? Probably matches the use case as described by OP.

Comment: Version 2.27. Yes, it does not match if the number it is at the beginning or the end of the text. Author said "in the middle of text", but it would be interesting to have a solution that takes that into account.

Answer (score 0):

it supports to match at start/end of line/string

```
(?<=[A-z])\d{1,2}(?=[A-z])
```

input

> jdjkj23kljl" or "kjflk2jk1234lj2 12sdfsdf12 hujng 12 hung

output

> jdjkj**23**kljl" or "kjflk**2**jk1234lj2 12sdfsdf12 hujng 12 hung

Comment: Is it supposed to match two digits at the start like "12d" or two digits at the end like "d12"? I think it does not.

Comment: can you write input and output?

Comment: Who are you asking?

Comment: To clarify my comment, you are stating "it supports to match at start/end of line/string", but I doubt that because of my test of your regex with the input "12d" and "d12". The "12" part is not matched in either test case.

Comment: By the way, you might want to take the [tour], to get some useful information on how StackOverflow is supposed to work.

Comment: Is there a special reason for including the special characters between 'Z'  and 'a' in your character groups `[A-z]` ? E.g. `[]\^_`.

Comment: @Yunnosch Thank you very much. im going to research more